# Difference between JsonWireProtocol mechanisms and the new standards in W3C Living Document when using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, w3c, webdriver-w3c-spec

I'm wondering what are the differences between the mechanisms in JsonWireProtocol (*Status: OBSOLETE*) and W3C Living Document from 31 December 2019 (*the new standard*) when using Selenium for UI tests. I know that Selenium have used the following: 
When we make a new instance of a driver (C#):

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

we actually make a *POST /session* request to the selenium server. 
After that via JsonWireProtocol and, in example:

*POST /session/:sessionId/element/:id/click*, we can find and click on particular element, or make some other actions with the other requests...

So what are the new things nowadays? Can someone explain the new standard?! I will be very happy if someone do that in-depth!

[WebDriver W3C Living Document 31 December 2019](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/)

[JsonWireProtocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The WebDriver Wire Protocol

The initial [WebDriver Wire Protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol/0d58cc79e7b851e4726bf06c85171291c44415fc) draft was a proposal that, all implementations of WebDriver that would communicate with the browser, or a RemoteWebDriver server shall use a common wire protocol. This wire protocol defined a [RESTful web service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html) using [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) over HTTP.

As per the initial proposal and practice some of the JSON Objects were as follows:

- [WebElement JSON Object](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#webelement-json-object): The JSON representation of a WebElement for transmission over the wire. This object will have the following properties:

[image: WebElement JSON Object]

- [Capabilities JSON Object](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#capabilities-json-object): Not all server implementations will support every WebDriver feature. Therefore, the client and server should use JSON objects with the properties listed below when describing which features a session supports.
- [Desired Capabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#desired-capabilities): A Capabilities JSON Object sent by the client describing the capabilities a new session created by the server should possess. Any omitted keys implicitly indicate the corresponding capability is irrelevant. More at [DesiredCapabilities](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/SeleniumHQ/selenium/DesiredCapabilities.md).
- [Actual Capabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#actual-capabilities): A Capabilities JSON Object returned by the server describing what features a session actually supports. Any omitted keys implicitly indicate the corresponding capability is not supported.
- etc

---

### WebDriver W3C Specification

With the introduction of [WebDriver W3C Specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) the following standards were defined:

- WebDriver remote ends must provide an HTTP compliant wire protocol where the **endpoints** map to different commands.
- Though this standard only defines the remote end protocol, it puts no demands to how local ends should be implemented.
- Local ends are only expected to be compatible to the extent that they can speak the remote end’s protocol; no requirements are made upon their exposed user-facing API.

---

### Commands

The WebDriver protocol is organised into commands. Each HTTP request with a method and template defined in this specification represents a single command, and therefore each command produces a single HTTP response. In response to a command, a remote end will run a series of actions known as remote end steps. These provide the sequences of actions that a remote end takes when it receives a particular command.

---

### Endpoints

The table of endpoints below lists the method and URI template for each endpoint node command and their [current support](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/chromedriver_status.md) in [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871).

[image: chromeScreenshot]

### Outro

[What is the difference between Protocol and Json Wire Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382080/what-is-the-difference-between-protocol-and-json-wire-protocol/54421235#54421235)